# MediaWiki template with links and inline html tag

Tags: mediawiki

i am trying to create a simple template that has 2 variable in Mediawiki.

variable 1 is the link whatever someone type: file://test.txt
variable 2 is the title: Test Document

The template would generate the hyperlink such as this:

[TestDocument](http://file://test.txt)

But behind this test document link it has this wiki syntax:

```
<ext>file://test.txt</ext>
```

Could someone assist with this?
Here is the sample of wiki syntax i tried testing:

```
<ext>{{{1}}}|{{{2}}}</ext>

<noinclude>
<ext>{{{1}}}|{{{2}}}</ext>
<noinclude>
<templatedata>
{
    "params": {
        "1": {
            "label": "Link",
            "description": "Link",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "file://test.txt",
            "required": true
        },
        "2": {
            "label": "Description:",
            "description": "Text",
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        }
    },
    "description": "links",
    "paramOrder": [
        "1",
        "2"
    ]
}
</templatedata>
</noinclude>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `$wgUrlProtocols [] = 'file://';` to your `LocalSettings.php`, you can simply use external link syntax: `[{{{1}}} {{{2}}}]`.